# PHP PDO Service No Data

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have the below REST web service that I am using to get user information from User table:

```
$name = htmlentities($_GET["name"]);
$name = strtoupper($name);


$dbh = new PDO("oci:dbname= $dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from Users where username =:name");

    $sth->bindParam(':name', $name);

    $sth->execute();

    $result = array();

$result["User"] = $sth->fetchAll((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

print_r ($result); //returns no data
```

When I print out the results, no data is returned. If I hard code a username value instead of using :name, then data comes back:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from Users where username ='TESTUSER'");
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the binding of the variable that is causing the SQL to run incorrectly. I tried using bindValue and bindParam and still returns no data. I am not recieving any errors, just no data.

**UPDATE:** It looks like the syntax is correct. Is there anything on the Oracle side that would prevent a prepared statement from being run?

Comment: 1. `print_r($name)` make sure it's what you expect. 
 2. `bindValue('name', $name);` don't use the colon in bindValue.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas printing name returns the value that I expect to be passed to the query. removing the colon still returns no results.

Comment: ... and that `print_r` showed you "TESTUSER"?

Comment: @TonyChiboucas yes. It shows what ever I pass in my rest url string name parameter.

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss, but there's a hacky test you can try to make sure it's not some weird encoding trouble. Just above `$sth = ...`, set a test-user's username (by ID) to `$name`. Aside from that, or maybe a PDO config issue (check `phpInfo()`), I'm not sure where to point you.

Comment: This is running on a server that has 2 other PDO services that are pretty much the same and those two work but for some reason this one isn't. I set a username to a variable and then tried to bind it and it still returned no data. Something is off with binding the variable.

Comment: Time for some deep debugging of that PDO service. Fastest thing to do would get XDebug working, and step through.

Comment: Does the name contains characters that are affected by htmlentities()?

Comment: @Dormilich No it shouldn't, they are just normal string usernames with no special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why data wasn't returning on the query. The database has the username field set as a CHAR(8) and usernames that were being passed only had 7 characters so it was failing. I need to append a blank space at the end of the string for it to match.